# C printing array numbers

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
  int numbers, counter;

  printf("How many numbers? \n");
  scanf("%d", &numbers);

  int array[numbers];

  printf("\nEnter the numbers: \n");
  for (;counter = 1; counter <= numere; counter++) {
    scanf("\n%d", &array[counter]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

How can I print from input numbers how many numbers are less than 10, how many are greater than 10, and how many are equal to 10?

Comment: You write a loop for it? By the way your `for` loop for reading is already wrong - arrays in C are 0-based and your loop writes 1 past the last allocated element, invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: Arrays first index is not one but zero. Does it compile?  Please sort out the format. Where is the rest of the code

Comment: `for(;counter=1;counter<=numere;counter++)` has 1 too many `;` in it.

Comment: @chux - there is also a typo

Comment: You really don't need to keep the numbers in the array unless there's other processing to be done afterwards.  You can simply read each number in turn and classify it, incrementing the appropriate counter.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create three variables to keep track of the counts.
2. Initialize each one to zero.
3. For each element of the array,

   1. Add one to the count of elements less than 10 if the element is less than 10.
   2. Add one to the count of elements equal to 10 if the element is equal to 10.
   3. Add one to the count of elements greater than 10 if the element is greater than 10.
4. Print the number of elements less than 10.
5. Print the number of elements equal to 10.
6. Print the number of elements greater than 10.